# How to put a different name on outlook.com alias?

Tags: outlook.com

I have my main address with my real first name and last name. I set up an alias, but when I send emails with it, I don't want my real first and last names to appear. In other words, I want a different screen name for each address.

How do I do this?

Comment: I don't think this is a feature of Outlook.com yet. You could always set up another account and link them

Comment: good point, if you can put this as your answer I will mark it as answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From comments:

I don't think this is a feature of Outlook.com yet. You could always set up another account and link them. To manage linked accounts, or to link a new account, visit [account.live.com/ManageLinks](https://account.live.com/ManageLinks)

Answer (score 3):

Microsoft removed linked accounts from outlook.com.

> Microsoft said Monday that it is eliminating the ability to link accounts within Outlook.com, replacing them with aliases instead.

[Source](http://www.pcworld.com/article/2042258/microsoft-kills-linked-accounts-in-outlook-com.html).